# Auto increment through a php loop

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have a case where I am using the code below to populate a template of sorts. Within the templates' javascript I would individually check the data attribute field I setup, essentially causing me to have multiple JS files instead of one that is shared. I then thought I could use a generic name field too, but prepend a number through the loop.

For example, with the line of code below where the `name="testField". I want to see if there is a way that I can add a number, but auto increment it through the loop with php.

Is this possible?

```
echo '<div class="markerItem" name="testField' . $number . '" "data-marker="' . $marker_data . '">';
```

PHP Code

```
if ($marker_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_marker)) {
    $marker_stmt->execute();
    $marker_rows = $marker_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<div id="projMarker">';
    foreach ($marker_rows as $marker_row) {
        $marker_solution = $marker_row['solution'];
        $maker_item = $marker_row['subSolution'];
        $marker_data = $marker_row['subSolution'];
        echo '<div class="markerItem" data-marker="' . $marker_data . '">';
            echo $marker_item;
            echo '</div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: `$number = 0; $number++;`

Comment: Or `foreach ($marker_rows as $number => $marker_row) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suprisingly, I couldn't find an appropriate duplicate for this.

You can easily [increment or decrement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) variables in PHP.

```
$number = 0;
foreach ($marker_rows as $marker_row) {
     ...
     $number++; // $number will now be $number+1
}
```

You can use $number++ directly in your attribute (if concatenating) as this will return the current $number then increment the value.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($marker_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_marker)) {
    $marker_stmt->execute();
    $marker_rows = $marker_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<div id="projMarker">';
    foreach ($marker_rows as $key=>$marker_row) {
        $marker_solution = $marker_row['solution'];
        $maker_item = $marker_row['subSolution'];
        $marker_data = $marker_row['subSolution'];
        echo '<div class="markerItem" name="testField_'.$key.'" data-marker="' . $marker_data . '">';
            echo $marker_item;
            echo '</div>';
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Using this, $key is assigned from the array index which will be a number starting from 0 and ending at `count($marker_rows)-1`.